# Посоветуйте книгу по физике и математике в программировании

Tags: книги, разработка-игр, математика, физика

Дошло дело до моделирования простейшего маятника и я понял, что не знаю как его сделать. Все что получается похоже на франкенштейна. Начал гуглить и не нашел. По этому если кто-то знает книги по физике и математике именно для программистов, делитесь авторами и названиями.

Comment: вы, кажется, ищете самый простой учебник по механике

Comment: смотрите книги по Численным методам. Рано вам в gamedev.

Comment: Etki, да! Спасибо.
ArchDemon, а я Вас и не спрашиваю и не советую советовать, а то окажется что Вы чужой  физ движок используете и тем самым являетесь недоделанным программистом каким хотите показать меня. По этому давайте советы тем, кто вас об этом просит и оценивайте только свои способности, а то всегда найдется тот, кто может больше и тогда по вашему же соображению дорога только одна - учить!

Comment: [Физика для разработчиков компьютерных игр](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7577936/) + CD  / (впрочем, можете  погуглить и др. ее источники)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А в чем проблема в маятнике?

Пишите Лагранжиан(разность кинетической и потенциальной энергии) для одной обобщенной координаты(угла). Подставляете его в одно уравнение Лагранжа.

Получаете диф. уравнение движения:

```
(alfa)'' + sin(alfa)*g/l = 0 (alfa - угол, l - длина плеча, g - ускорение свободного падения)
```

делаете там замену `sin(alfa)=alfa`, так как в общем случае уравнение нелинейно.

Решаете его как обычное линейное. Получаете **явную** формулу для координаты и периода в случае малых углов.

```
alfa(t)=a_0*cos(sqrt(g/l)*t)
T=2*Pi*sqrt(l/g)
```

Все. Это на 1 курсе проходят любого техвуза же.